# Adding a custom request header to AWS ALB through Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, cors, aws-application-load-balancer

I have configured a AWS ALB to forward traffic to a specific port of my Node.js server based on the request header "api-target". Problem is, when sending CORS preflight request, this header is not generated by the browser, leading to (as I understand it) the traffic not being routed correctly thus making the server send and error masked as a CORS error.

[image]

Screenshot of the ALB rules as reference:
[image]

I want to append the request header "api-target" with a specified value based on the URL-path. To my understanding, this can't be done strictly in ALB, but it can be achieved by combining ALB with Lambda functions. I have experimented with creating different lambda functions that could append the mentioned header to the request and then forward the traffic to the ALB rules (or even straight to the target groups that the rules in turn forward to). Thus far I have not been successful and I hope that you guys could have a better idea of how I should go about this since I am relatively new to AWS. Below are the approaches I have tested.

**Test case 1**

Simply appending the desired header based on the url and then attaching a trigger that (should) activate the lambda function once any traffic hits the ALB. Problem here is that the trigger does not seem to be activated for reasons that are unknown to me.

Reference pictures:

[image]

[image]

**Test case 2**

Attempting to forward the request to the ARN of the desired target group through the lambda function.

Reference picture:
[image]

Then adding a rule to the ALB telling it to forward all OPTIONS-requests to the lambda function.

Reference pictures:
[image]

[image]

This results in a BAD GATEWAY response when sending an OPTIONS-request towards the destination.

Comment: Using custom request headers for this is really non-standard. If you want to do this for certain paths, just so they will eventually be routed by the ALB to the correct target, why not just use path routing for those paths directly in the ALB?

Comment: By the way, the way you are trying to use a Lambda function is not going to work. The purpose of the Lambda integration with ALB isn't to modify the requests before the ALB decides what to do with the request. The purpose is to allow the Lambda function to actually generate the response. In your case that stuff you are doing in the Lambda function is just being returned as a response directly to the client that made the request. The Load balancer doesn't re-evaluate the request after the Lambda function is done.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! In regards to your first reply. If I do the path routing directly in the ALB I still wont be able to modify the request headers. At least not through ALB to my understanding. Could you recommend an approach to include the desired request header in the preflight request (or any request) depending on the URL path?

Comment: My recommendation is to not use a custom request header for this at all. You said your ALB forwards traffic based on a request header. That entire idea is what has led you to have the problem you are having in the first place. I'm saying stop doing request header routing, and do path based routing instead.